# Facing issue with uploading file to ftp server

Tags: ios, iphone, ftp, core-foundation, nsurlsession

While I'm trying to upload a file through FTP using `NSURLSession` I'm facing permission issue. But while trying with `Core Foundation` framework file is not uploading but a file is getting created with the name I provided in code, even not facing any permission issue. For both I'm passing same credentials. If any one wants to see code please let me know I'll upload it. I want to add functionality of pause and resume too. So I'm not using any library even I want to implement it by myself so that I can learn about.

Comment: You can use CFNetwork framework and add SCRFTPRequest.h and SCRFTPRequest.m file from github to your project to upload file to FTP Server.

Comment: shall I add the code for you?

Comment: @Dream Yes of course, you can. It will be really appreciable. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In order to upload file to FTP Server, NSURLConnection cannot be used, instead SCRFTPConnection is used. You need to include CFNetwork framework. Also, below is the link to download SCRFTPRequest.h and SCRFTPRequest.m file from Github

https://github.com/Hackmodford/SCRFTPRequest

Copy just .h and .m file from the above zip file you download from Github and add it in your project.

// IN .H FILE OF YOUR VIEW CONTROLLER

Import the "SCRFTPRequest.h" file and add the delegate,

// IN .M FILE OF YOUR VIEW CONTROLLER

```
-(void)uploadFileUsingSCRFTPRequest{
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

    NSString *file_name=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"TEST.txt"];
    NSString *myPathDocs =  [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:file_name];

    SCRFTPRequest *ftpRequest = [[SCRFTPRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"ftp://your_url/"] toUploadFile:myPathDocs];

    ftpRequest.username = @"username";
    ftpRequest.password = @"password";

    ftpRequest.delegate = self;

    [ftpRequest startRequest];

}

- (void)ftpRequestDidFinish:(SCRFTPRequest *)request {
    NSLog(@"Upload finished.");
}

- (void)ftpRequest:(SCRFTPRequest *)request didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {

    NSString *str=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Upload failed: %@", [error localizedDescription]];
    NSLog(@"Upload failed: %@", [error localizedDescription]);

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I'll check and let u know.